# How to create multi scale chart？

Tags: chart.js

My problems is how to create multi scale chart using chartJS.
For example.
In one graph, the X-axis starts from 0 on the scale and advances by 10 steps, and then the scale reaches 70, it advances by 30 steps.

if you know Could you tell me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFlr0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to write your own custom scale which achieves this (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/developers/axes.html) or use the logarithmic scale which comes the closest to this behaviour (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/scales/log.html)

Comment: Thnak you for answerd my problem.

I'll try using new axes!